# Interpreting intercept in logistic regression when there is more than one categorical variable

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-encoding, intercept

```
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
#create a binary variable just for the purpose of experimentation
mydata$bin = rbinom(nrow(mydata), p = 0.7, size = 1)
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mydata$bin <- factor(mydata$bin)
#Run the model with just bin
my.mod <- glm(admit ~ bin, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
summary(my.mod)
```

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error  z value    Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) **-0.8434294**  0.1966085 -4.28989 0.000017876
bin1         0.1121304  0.2347628  0.47763     0.63291

The intercept is simply logodds of admit == 1 when bin1 = 0

Check:

```
x = subset(mydata, bin == "0")
mean(x$admit)
log(0.3008130081/(1-0.3008130081))
```

Result:
    **-0.843429383**
Tallied

Next, do the same with rank variable alone in the model

```
my.mod <- glm(admit ~ rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
summary(my.mod)
```

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error  z value    Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  **0.1643031**  0.2569384  0.63946    0.522521
rank2       -0.7500300  0.3079693 -2.43540    0.014875
rank3       -1.3646980  0.3353867 -4.06903 0.000047210
rank4       -1.6867296  0.4093073 -4.12094 0.000037733

The intercept is simply logodds of admit == 1 when rank2 = 0 & rank3 = 0 & rank4 = 0; in other words rank == 1

Check:

```
x = subset(mydata, rank == "1" )
mean(x$admit)
log(0.5409836066/(1-0.5409836066))
```

Result:
   **0.1643030515** Tallied

Next, I add both the categorical variables in the model

```
my.mod <- glm(admit ~ rank + bin, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
summary(my.mod)
```

Coefficients:
               Estimate  Std. Error  z value    Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  **0.23245129**  0.32715773  0.71052    0.477383
rank2       -0.75673758  0.30869909 -2.45138    0.014231
rank3       -1.38523274  0.34119770 -4.05991 0.000049091
rank4       -1.69956417  0.41127752 -4.13240 0.000035899
bin1        -0.08308446  0.24667503 -0.33682    0.736255

**Question**: How to make sense of this intercept like above 2 examples? I don't think in this case intercept equals logodds of admit == 1 when (bin = 0 and rank = 1).

Check:

```
 x = subset(mydata, rank == "1" & bin == "0" )
 mean(x$admit)
 log(0.6363636364/(1-0.6363636364))
```

Result: 
     **0.5596157881** Not tallied!

Answer (score 1):

So, you have two binary predictors, say $X$ and $Z$, and the logistic model
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\P(Y=1 \mid X=x) = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x}}{1+e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x}}
$$
setting $X=0$ you can see that $\beta_0$ is the log odds of probability that $Y=1$ given $X=0$.  Now adding the second predictor in the model:
$$
\P(Y=1 \mid X=x,Z=z) = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x+\beta_2 z}}{1+e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 z}}
$$
and you can see that in this model $\beta_0$ is the log odds of the probability that $Y=1$ given **both** $X=0$ and $Z=0$ (in your code example you look at the conditioning $X=0, Z=1$).

Comment: dummy variables for the categorical variable with rank = 1 as the baseline are all zero. bin1 is also zero for binary predictor for bin = 0. This will wipe out all the terms in the linear predictor except for the intercept - β0. Ex - > model.matrix(my.mod)[13,]
(Intercept)        bin1       rank2       rank3       rank4 
          1           0           0           0           0                                                            ..I still cannot see the answer, some elaboration would surely help.

Comment: > mydata[13,]
   ADMIT GRE GPA RANK bin rank
13     1 760   4    1   0    1